# options to add information to cells, other than in the cell itself in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to store custom information (metadata) together with some cells in Excel using VBA.

Option 1 seems to be the common solution, Option 2 is the one I devised.

Option 1: The first (standard) solution I found online is the method of using another worksheet to store the additional information. This worksheet is then hidden from view to the user. I find this a little awkward.

Option 2: Unless the worksheet is intended to be exported to html, the .ID parameter of the cell is going to be unused. So all one has to do is change the ID to whatever data one wants to store, and voila! Instant spare data field.

As hinted at, care has to be taken when exporting to html, however.

Option 3: One could use the comments. But in this case the information would be exposed to the user. If it is a lot of info, it may be annoying. If it is important information, the user may modify / delete it.

Now my questions:

a) Is there another way to store data together with a cell other than the two options above?

b) has anyone used Option B before and found any limits (except html related). I have not tested how much data one can store in this field. Any ideas?

Comment: It may be due to hardware, but I couldn't put a string longer than 318,341,104 total length in characters in the ID field.  That length and lower was fine, and seeing as how the entire Lord of the Rings trilogy contains 481,103 words, each word would have to have a length of over 650 characters in order to reach that character limit.  So that's a really large number and not really limiting at all.  It handles numbers the same way Excel cells handle numbers (precision to 15 digits, same large and small limitations as Double variables).  It can also only seem to handle ascii characters

Comment: Option 3 - store in cell comments

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, I have done that too in the past, I did not specify that the meta information should be hidden from view. let me amend the question

Comment: Storing data in `ID` does not persist across a file close/reopen.  Is this an issue for you?

Comment: Option 4 - hidden `Names`, Option 5 - [Custom XML Parts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608618(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @chrisneilsen For what I have been doing, having the info persistent was not necessary, but I honestly did not realise that the data is dropped when closing Excel.